# What is an example of a smooth function in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ which is not contained in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})\otimes C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, smooth-manifolds, algebras

When looking at the tensor product of the ring of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is only an injection
$$
C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\otimes_\mathbb{R}C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^m) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n+m})
$$
This motivates the construction of the completed tensor product which gives an isomorphism. What is an example of a smooth function which in
$$
C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)
$$
which does not lie in the standard tensor product?

Comment: How about $f(x,y) = x + y$? I think any function which is not a product is an example.

Comment: Why isn't that $x\otimes 1 + 1 \otimes y$?

Comment: I am sorry. I was careless.

Comment: So how about $f(x,y)=\sin(x+y)$?

Comment: $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y) = \sin(x)\otimes\cos(y) + \cos(x)\otimes\sin(y)$

Comment: @AmitaiYuval It has to be found as a limit of smooth functions which is not convergent, but converges with respect to one of the topological tensor product topologies, the $\pi$-topology or the $\varepsilon$-topology.

Comment: This is fun! How about $\frac{1}{x+y}$?

Comment: its not smooth on $V(x+y)$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assume that $H \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function that has the form $H(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^k f_i(x)g_i(y)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and some functions $f_i,g_i \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then for each fixed $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ the function $y \mapsto H(x_0,y)$ is a linear combination of the functions $g_1, \dots, g_k$ (with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$). In particular, for any $n > k$ the functions

$$ y \mapsto H(1,y), y \mapsto H(2,y), \dots, y \mapsto H(n,y) $$

must be linearly dependent (because they all belong to $\operatorname{span} \{ g_1, \dots, g_k \}$).

So consider for example $H(x,y) = e^{xy}$ and assume that $H = \sum_{i=1}^k f_i(x)g_i(y)$ for some $k$ and $f_i,g_i$. It is readily [seen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241883/how-to-prove-that-this-set-of-elements-are-linearly-independent/2241897#2241897) that the functions

$$ e^{y}, e^{2y}, \dots, e^{ky}, e^{(k+1)y} $$

are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$ and we arrived a contradiction.